# Render Geometric Tolerance in ezdxf

Tags: python, matplotlib, ezdxf

Is Geometric Tolerance supported by ezdxf? I've been trying to render some dxf files with geometric tolerances like;
-Flatness
-Position
-Runout
-Parallelism
-Perpendicity, etc
But I get a "**skipped entity TOLERANCE(#!!). Reason: "unsupported"**"
Is there a workaround to render them, or are there plans to support this?
I've used the code given in the documentation to render the dxf using matplotlib:
https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/addons/drawing.html

Here is the dxf from Autodesk viewer and the render from ezdxf:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have been looking for the same thing, looks like it is unsupported .

Comment: @Anuradha yes it seems so https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/issues/598#event-5900458613